# Web sql/Sql Lite and Binding to Row in Angular

Tags: sqlite, angularjs, cordova, web-sql

This is for a phonegap angular app.  I would have thought binding to the db query return, `result.rows` in my case would be possible but it seems like it is not.   The only way I could get this to work was with the commented out code where I manually push the data into an array row by row.  Is this the only way?

The actually error received by binding to `.rows` is:  `Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: item in items key: undefined:undefined`

The service:

```
// only portion of code shown
query: function (q) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        var db = this.getDb();

        db.transaction(function (t) {
            t.executeSql(q, [], function (tx, results) {
                d.resolve(results);
            }, function (err) {
                d.reject(err);
            });

        }, function (err) {
            d.reject(err);
        }
        );

        return d.promise;
     }
```

The controller is like this:

```
  Sql.query('select * from DEMO').then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //$scope.items = [];

                //for (i = 0, l = data.rows.length; i < l; i++) {
                    //$scope.items.push(data.rows.item(i));
                //}

                $scope.items = data.rows;  // this errors out
                $scope.$safeApply();
            });
```

The repeater is just a simple:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.id}} {{item.data}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message it looks like you have more than one `undefined` item in the `data.rows` array.

Your working code uses `data.rows.item(i)` is that creating an new empty object instead of undefined? Try changing `data.rows.item(i)` to `data.rows[i]` in your working code does that break as well?

Assuming you are using angular 1.1.5 here are some options:

- Use your current workaround
- Downgrade to 1.1.4 or to the current stable 1.0.7. I think 1.1.4 will work based on a [broken version with 1.1.5](http://plnkr.co/edit/MVdfWvSBFqpOzerpYlBl?p=preview) and a [working version with 1.1.4](http://plnkr.co/edit/kixJdfBSpJK2hls7NOSZ?p=preview).
- Remove any duplicate `undefined` rows from `data.rows`

---

Note: For others having a similar type of error Angular generates a `$$hashKey` to objects when doing an `ng-repeat`. This error indicates the same object is in the array (with the same `$$hashKey`) and is not allowed in 1.1.5 (and later?).

See this [blog post](http://mutablethought.com/2013/04/25/angular-js-ng-repeat-no-longer-allowing-duplicates/) and [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/pI0IgNHKjxw) for more info. Also this [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2216) looks related so I'm not sure if this behavior is intended going forward though it appears to have been fixed in the past.

Comment: The query I am running only has two columns and two rows of data, id and data, both of which have and display data.  I will downgrade the version and report back if that fixes it.

Comment: I just had a chance to test this and experienced similar problems with both 1.1.4 and 1.1.5.. Backing down to 1.0.7 fixed it for anyone else having hashkey issues.